# How can I implement cross-device sync for an iOS PhoneGap app with a WebSQL database?

Tags: ios, cordova, synchronization, web-sql

I have a PhoneGap app (currenly iOS-only) that stores all of the user's data in a WebSQL database. I would like users to be able to sync their data across their iOS devices.

What options are available to do this? And which are the most tried and tested?